# Don't notify contacts when starting teamviewer

Tags: windows, windows-10, teamviewer

Is it possible to start Teamviewer without notifying my contacts that I started it? Sometimes I want to start TeamViewer, but I do not want my contacts to know that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this: Extras -> Options -> Advanced -> Show advanced options -> **Hide online status for this ID**

[image]

Comment: Searched everywhere but couldn't find it. Now I do! Thanks